# Identify a language in which the previous one was recorded

Tags: .net, powershell

I want to insert users from AD into SQL
I found a code that performs this topic and the code is

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
Set-StrictMode -Version 3

$DataArray = @(Get-ADUser -AuthType 0 -ResultSetSize 10 -filter {Name -eq 'user name'})


$DataTable = [System.Data.DataTable]::new()

$DataTable.Columns.Add([System.Data.DataColumn]::new('name', [String]))
$DataTable.Columns.Add([System.Data.DataColumn]::new('ObjectClass', [String]))

$ColumnNamesArray = @($DataTable.Columns.ColumnName)

foreach ($DataElement in $DataArray) {
    $NewRow = $DataTable.NewRow()

    foreach ($ColumnName in $ColumnNamesArray) {
        $NewRow.$ColumnName = $DataElement.$ColumnName
    }

    $DataTable.Rows.Add($NewRow)
}

$NumOfRows = $DataTable.Rows.Count 

if ($NumOfRows -ne 0)
{
    $SqlServerName = 'localhost'
    $SqlDatabaseName = 'test'
    $BatchSizeRows = 1000
    $BulkCopyTimeOutSeconds = 60
    # $SqlServerUserName = 'SqlAdmin'
    # $SqlServerUserPassword = ''

    $SqlTableName= '[dbo].[TableName]'

    # $SqlServerUserPasswordSecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $SqlServerUserPassword -AsPlainText -Force
    # $SqlServerUserPsCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($SqlServerUserName, $SqlServerUserPasswordSecureString)

    $WriteDbaDataTableParameters = @{
        'SqlInstance'     = $SqlServerName
        'Database'        = $SqlDatabaseName
        # 'SqlCredential'   = $SqlServerUserPsCredential
        'BatchSize'       = $BatchSizeRows
        'BulkCopyTimeOut' = $BulkCopyTimeOutSeconds
        'EnableException' = $true
    }

    Write-DbaDataTable @WriteDbaDataTableParameters -Table $SqlTableName -InputObject $DataTable
}
```

I know the POWERSHELL commands very well I would love to help you understand which language and what these commands do:
[System.Data.DataColumn]
I would be happy for help with a link to an explanation of SQL connection commands via POWERSHELL

Comment: This **is** Powershell, it's just [creating .Net objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_object_creation?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Thanks a lot Another question I am running the previous line and get an error:
Write-DbaDataTable : The term 'Write-DbaDataTable' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:52 char:5
+     Write-DbaDataTable @WriteDbaDataTableParameters -Table $SqlTableN ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Write-DbaDataTable:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

Comment: Looks like it's part of [dbatools PS package](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/dbatools/0.8.694/Content/functions%5CWrite-DbaDataTable.ps1)

Comment: I tried it but it did not work